# Acess javascript textbox value to a jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01  Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addElement() 
{ 

if(intTextBox==1)
{
var contentID = document.getElementById('content'); 
var newTBDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox); 
newTBDiv.innerHTML = "S.No <input type='text' id='sno' />          Name<input    type='text' id='name' />"; 
contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv); 
intTextBox=0;
}
} 


function removeElement() 
{ 
intTextBox=1;
var contentID = document.getElementById('content'); 
contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('strText'+intTextBox)); 
} 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p><a href="javascript:addElement();" >Add</a> <a href="javascript:removeElement();"     >Remove</a></p> 
            <div id="content"></div>
<%
String name=request.getParameter("sno");
if(name!=null){
out.println(name);
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi all please help me I stuck with one problem.The problem is i have a textbox in javascript how to access the textbox **value in javascript to a jsp page**.Is there any way to access the value.

Comment: And no searching found anything?! Getting a text input value... tons of examples on the web.

Comment: You need to use some kind of http request. So Ajax (DWR) or iframe or image loading

Comment: searched a lot but none of them give me a solution Dave Newton

Comment: I'm a little confused, what are you trying to do? Create a text box in JS and initialize it with a value from the server side? Do you already have the value from Java when you're rendering the page?

Comment: I have jsp page If any one clicks add link two text boxes will appear i will add button(which i have not written above).I will pass those values to servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Give the input field a name.

So instead of creating

```
<input type='text' id='sno' />
```

you should be creating

```
<input type='text' id='sno' name='sno' />
```

This way the submitted value is available in the request parameter map by this name.

```
String sno = request.getParameter("sno");
```